# How to get data from Shared Preferences into RecylerView Adapter and pass to next fragment

Tags: java, android

Trying to get data from shared preference into recylerview adapter but I'm getting `context = null`. I also initialized context in the adapter. I searched a lot but nothing helped me. Any tutorial or any help will be appreciated

**here is My adapter:-**

```
    public class HomeFeaturedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeFeaturedAdapter.HomeViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    public HomeFeaturedAdapter(List<Products> productList) {

        this.context = context;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HomeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.brand_adapter_row, parent, false);
        return new HomeViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeViewHolder homeViewHolder, int i) {

        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String imageload = preferences.getString("permalink", null);

        /*SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = ((HomeViewHolder) homeViewHolder).imageload.getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);*/

        /*SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.context);
        String imageload = sharedPreferences.getString("permalink", null);*/


        if (imageload != null) {

            Picasso.with(context).load(imageload).fit().into(homeViewHolder.imagesViews);

        }

/*
        homeViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                Fragment myFragment = new ProductDetailsFragment();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainfraime, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
*/

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    public class HomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public View view;
        TextView productTitle;
        ImageView imagesViews;
        CardView brandCardview;

        public HomeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.view = itemView;

            productTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productTitle);
            imagesViews = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagesViews);
            brandCardview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brandCardview);
        }
    }
}
```

**If I add context in the constructor like this**

```
` 

    public HomeFeaturedAdapter(Context context, List<Products> productList) {

            this.context = context;
        }

`
```

I'm getting in my Home Fragment `error: constructor HomeFeaturedAdapter in class HomeFeaturedAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
        HomeFeaturedAdapter adapter = new HomeFeaturedAdapter(productList);`

Please help me to find a solution I tried a lot on google but not understanding what to do.

Comment: don't do that, should passing list of data from activity to adapter because when scrolling get data from SharePreference => low FPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added Context to the adapter constructor, so when you call this constructor from your fragment or activity you need to add context. If you call it from an Activity call

```
 HomeFeaturedAdapter adapter = new HomeFeaturedAdapter(this, productList)
```

From Fragment you can call

```
HomeFeaturedAdapter adapter = new HomeFeaturedAdapter(getActivity(), productList)
```

Comment: thanks@MorZa Now i'm getting `context = Mainactivity@4629` but still image is not loading in recylerview.

Comment: Try to debug and check if (imageload != null)

Answer (score 0):

```
HomeFeaturedAdapter adapter = new HomeFeaturedAdapter(productList)
```

You are using the wrong constructor to make the object of an adapter.You have to use this one

```
HomeFeaturedAdapter adapter = new HomeFeaturedAdapter(getContext(),productList);
```

You are using multiple constructors in the adapter so you are using the one without `context` so your `context` is null in the adapter.

Comment: I used with `getContext()` this solved my costructor error but image is not loading in recylerview.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will Help You. This is correct code i already tried it!

```
public class HomeFeaturedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeFeaturedAdapter.HomeViewHolder> {

Context context;

public HomeFeaturedAdapter (Context context, List<Products> productList) {
    this.context = context;
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HomeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.brand_adapter_row, parent, false);
    return new HomeViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeViewHolder homeViewHolder, int i) {

    String imageload = preferences.getString("permalink", null);
    if (imageload != null) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(imageload).fit().into(homeViewHolder.imagesViews);

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 10;
}

public class HomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public View view;
    TextView productTitle;
    ImageView imagesViews;
    CardView brandCardview;

    public HomeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.view = itemView;

        productTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productTitle);
        imagesViews = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagesViews);
        brandCardview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brandCardview);
    }
}
```

}

And in your fragment do like this

```
HomeFeaturedAdapter adapter = new HomeFeaturedAdapter(getActivity(), productList);
```